# How do I assign a column variable to winform textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

have the following query

```
 <WebMethod(Description:="Retrieve members of a Client List"), SoapHeader("MessageSoapHeader", direction:=SoapHeaderDirection.In)> _
    Public Function GetClientListMembers() As DataSet
        Dim RS As SqlDataReader
        RS = objApp.ConnectUser(MessageSoapHeader.UID, MessageSoapHeader.PWD, MessageSoapHeader.Campaign, MessageSoapHeader.Keyword, LocalCommon.apSOAPAdvanced)
        If objApp.ClassErrorsCount > 0 Then
            Dim NX As New Exception
            LLIB.ThrowSOAPException(objApp.Errors(1).Number, NX, objApp.DB, objApp.Errors(1).ErrorType, objApp.Errors(1).Description)
            GetClientListMembers = New DataSet
            Exit Function
        End If

        Dim Client As New SqlCommand("optinPaging", objApp.DB)
        Client.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        AddSQLCmdParm(Client, "@Shortcode", SqlDbType.Int, "", objApp.ShortCode, 0)
        AddSQLCmdParm(Client, "@Keyword", SqlDbType.VarChar, "", objApp.Keyword, 0)

        GetClientListMembers = LLIB.GetDataSet(Client)

        LLIB.RecordRowTransfer(GetClientListMembers.Tables(0).Rows.Count, LLIB.RowTransferDirection.ToClient, objApp)
        LLIB.FunctionCount(objApp, "GetClientListMembers") 'This must be placed after the close of RS
        GetClientListMembers.Tables(0).TableName = "Cell Numbers"
        LLIB.RecordRowTransfer(GetClientListMembers.Tables(0).Rows.Count, LLIB.RowTransferDirection.ToClient, objApp)
        'Now get the email stuff
        LLIB.AddDataTable(GetClientListMembers, "Email Addresses", "SELECT EmailAddress,Keyword, dbo.fn_ToUTC(ActualOptInDate) AS ActualOptInDate FROM EmailOptins WHERE ShortCode='" & objApp.ShortCode & "' AND Keyword='" & objApp.Keyword & "' AND OptInState=2 ORDER BY EmailAddress", objApp)
        If GetClientListMembers.Tables.Count > 1 Then LLIB.RecordRowTransfer(GetClientListMembers.Tables(1).Rows.Count, LLIB.RowTransferDirection.ToClient, objApp)
        objApp.DB.Close()
    End Function
```

One of the columns it returns is `totalPages`. This value is the the same for all rows

I need to display this in a `textbox` on the form. The name of the textbox is "pageCount"

I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your client app you probably have something like this

```
ReturnedDS = AdvServer.GetClientListMembers()
```

Assuming that your database [stored procedure] call returns only one table

```
dim pgCount as integer = 0 'default value
' Check if your table actually has rows
If ReturnedDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    ' pick first row and specific column
    pgCount = CInt(myDataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)("totalPages"))

End If
' set text box
pageCount.Text = pgCount.ToString()
```

Comment: The query itself returns a 100 rows at a time. The value of totalPages is always the same. Will this make a difference?

Comment: @Portlight No, it will not. If you have no data, you will get no rows, so than it is `0` pages. Otherwise num of pages is the same in each batch or rows.

Comment: I added the code you posted and received the following error  "System.NullReferenceException: Object variable or With block variable not set." I added them to the same code block

Comment: Can we go to chat - comments limits my posting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55340/discussion-between-t-s-and-portlight).